# reading a file and/or a table from the computer in c++

Tags: c++, stream, structure

i have a c++ program that computes the average,variance,standard deviation and coefficient of variation of marks but it only reads values from the keyboard.
 am seeking help with a c++ program that computes all the above but reads values from the computer(ie reading a file and/or table with multiple columns from the computer and calculates all the above for all the columns independently like a football league table)
below is my draft program that i want to be modified to cater for all the above requirements

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<cmath>
#define MAXSIZE 1000
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void sd(void);
void average(void);
void variance(void);
void coeff(void);
void all(void);
float x[MAXSIZE];
int i=0, n, choice, c=0;
float avrg=0,var,stdv,cv, sum1=0, sum=0;

main()
{
      cout<<"Enter the numbers (press -200 when finished)\n";      
      int hasrun=0;                       
      for(int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)                        ///INTERCHANGE n WiTH c
                {
                if (hasrun == 0)
                   {
                    cin>>x[i];
                    if ( x[i] == -200 )
                       {
                       hasrun =1;
                       }
                    c++;
                   }
                   if(x[i]<0|x[i]>100)
                        {
                        break;
                        cout<<"\nthe entered value is invalid\n";
                        hasrun =1;
                        }
                }
 for(;;)
       {            
          cout<<"\n\nEnter Your Choice\n"
          "1.Calculate average\n"
          "2.Calculate variance\n"
          "3.Calculate standard deviation\n"
          "4.Calculate the coefficient of variation\n"
          "5.Display all\n"
          "6.end\n\n";          

           cin >> choice;
           int exit = 0;
         switch (choice)
                {
                 case 1: 
                      average();
                      break;
                 case 2:
                      variance();
                      break;
                 case 3:
                      sd();
                      break;
                 case 4:
                      coeff();
                      break;
                 case 5:
                      all();
                      break;
                 case 6: 
                      exit=1;
                      break;
                 default:
                         cout<<"invalid choice"<<endl;
                 }
         if (exit==1){
            break;}
       }     
}

 /* Compute the sum of all elements */
void average(void)
{ 
 sum = 0;    
 cout<<"\tMEAN OF STUDENTS MARKS:\n\t_____________________\n";    
 for(int j=0; j<(c-1); j++)
 {
  sum = sum + x[j];
 }
 avrg = sum /(float)(c-1);

 cout<<"\t\t";
 cout<<avrg;
 cout<<"\n\n";
//system("PAUSE");
}

void variance()
{
sum1=0;
     cout<<"\tVARIANCE OF THE STUDENTS MARKS:\n\t_______________________________\n";
for(i=0; i<(c-1); i++)
                 {
                  sum1 = sum1 + pow((x[i] - avrg),2);
                 }
                 var = (sum1 /(float)(c-1) );

                 cout<<"\t\t\t";
                 cout<<var;
                 cout<<"\n\n";
}

void sd()
{
     cout<<"\tSTANDARD DEVIATION OF THE STUDENTS MARKS:\n\t________________________________\n";
     stdv=sqrt(var);
 cout<<"\t\t\t";
 cout<<stdv;
 cout<<"\n\n";
}
void coeff()
{
    cout<<"\tCOEFFICIENT OF VARIATION:\n\t__________________________\n";
    cv=stdv/avrg;
    cout<<"\t\t\t";
    cout<<cv;
    cout<<"\n\n";
}
void all()
{
    cout<<"\tDISPLAY ALL:\n\t********************\n";
 cout<<"average=";
 cout<<avrg;
 cout<<"\n\n";
     cout<<"variance=";
     cout<<var;`enter code here`
     cout<<"\n\n";
         cout<<"standard deviation=";
         cout<<stdv;
         cout<<"\n\n";
             cout<<"coefficient of variation=";
             cout<<cv;
             cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

this is my own work, am just a student who loves trying out something new and i have taught most of the above functions myself.HELP..............

Comment: "#include<iostream.h>" - you must be a really old student...

Comment: For examples, try searching Stack Overflow for "[c++] read file variable"

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of the C++ streams libraries is that they behave the same regardless of where the data is coming form.  In you case, you just need to read about the [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) library, and read your data from a file instead of from standard input.

If youf file is line-based, I'll save you a further question and tell you you're probably going to want to read about the [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the file stream classes from the standard library.  You need to include `<fstream>`.  Then create an input file stream to read from your file:

```
ifstream fin( "myfile.txt" );
if( !fin ) {
     cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
}
```

Use the file stream in exactly the same way as you use the standard input stream (`cin`).